# How can I convert a list of lists in a Dataframe in Pyspark, being each list the values of each attribute?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, attributes, pyspark

I have a list of list of type:

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]
```

Each list contains the values of the attributes 'A1', 'A2', and 'A3'.

I want to get the next dataframe:

```
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| A1       | A2       | A3       |
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| 1        | A        | aa       |
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| 2        | B        | bb       |
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| 3        | C        | cc       |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a Row Class with the header as fields, and use `zip` to loop through the list row wise and construct a row object for each row:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]

from pyspark.sql import Row

R = Row("A1", "A2", "A3")
sc.parallelize([R(*r) for r in zip(*lst)]).toDF().show()
+---+---+---+
| A1| A2| A3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  A| aa|
|  2|  B| bb|
|  3|  C| cc|
+---+---+---+
```

---

Or if you have pandas installed, create a pandas data frame first; You can create a spark data frame from pandas data frame directly by using `spark.createDataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
headers = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(headers, lst)))
spark.createDataFrame(pdf).show()
+---+---+---+
| A1| A2| A3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  A| aa|
|  2|  B| bb|
|  3|  C| cc|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
names=['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
data=sc.parallelize(zip(*[[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']])).\
map(lambda x: Row(**{names[i]: elt for i, elt in enumerate(x)})).toDF()
```