# How can I convert a list of lists in a Dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a list of list of type:

```
[[1, 'A', 'aa'], [2 'B', 'bb'], [3, 'C', 'cc']]
```

I want to get the next dataframe:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | aa |
| 2 | B | bb |
| 3 | C | cc |

This solution is somewhat similar ,but list has data from same columns
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46891396/6463651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the list to create the dataframe directly.

```
data = [[1, 'A', 'aa'], [2, 'B', 'bb'], [3, 'C', 'cc']]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'col1', 'col2'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```